# Unable to Retrieve GUID from MS SQL Table field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I must be totally missing something as I have all kinds of data type fields in my MS SQL 2008 data tables and am able to retrive all the data correctly except for my newly added GUID data (uniqueidentifier type).
My .net app has a reader setup for the GUID field, but when I step the code and make the assignment to the local object there is never any data in it, it's just a empty GUID.
Running the same Stored Procedure in SSMS clearly shows the GUIDs being picked up in the result set.

Can anyone give me any clues as to what might be wrong or some debugging tips?
(Visual Studio 2008 .net 3.5, vb.net, MS SQL Server 2008 r1)

Here is my vb.net `iDataReader`

```
  Public Class DataReaderHelper
    Implements IDataReader

    Private _Reader As IDataReader
    Private strFields() As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal _DataReader As IDataReader)
        ' Load the fields array with uppercased field names in the reader
        ReDim strFields(0 To _DataReader.FieldCount - 1)
        For iIndex As Integer = 0 To _DataReader.FieldCount - 1
            strFields(iIndex) = _DataReader.GetName(iIndex).ToUpper
        Next
        _Reader = _DataReader
    End Sub

    Public Function FieldIndex(ByVal FieldName As String) As Integer
        ' Returns the ordinal position of the named field
        ' in the datareader, or a -1 if the field is not found
        Return Array.IndexOf(strFields, FieldName.ToUpper)
    End Function


#Region "SetObjectProperty overloads"
    ' Type-specific overloads to allow data object properties to
    ' be consistently populated with values if the encapsulated 
    ' data reader contains data for the specified field name.

    Public Sub SetObjectProperty(ByVal FieldName As String, _
                             ByRef ObjectProperty As Guid)
        ' Set the GUID object property if the referenced field exists
        ' in the data reader. If the field does not exist or is null,
        ' set the property to an empty GUID.
        Dim GuidValue As Guid
        Dim intIndex As Integer = FieldIndex(FieldName)
        If intIndex > -1 AndAlso Not _Reader.IsDBNull(intIndex) Then
            GuidValue = _Reader.GetGuid(intIndex)
        End If
        ObjectProperty = GuidValue

    End Sub
```

The Field name is right and the column index is right.
I stepped throught this code, but this line seems to do nothing in getting the value.
The `GuidValue` is always EMPTY as if `_Reader.GetGuid(intIndex)` does nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What data do you have? Are you sure it's a guid you have in the proper location? Are you sure it gets into your IF
Also you should remove unnecessary code from your question and only show the relevant section.

Comment: Ha, clearly you are to hung up on the unnecessary code to read the initial text. " I step the code and make the assignment". I also explained the data I'm working with. If I was 100% sure what was unnecessary I would probably have this issue solved, better to have to much then not enough to understand. As far as I know the only necessary line of code is: GuidValue = _Reader.GetGuid(IntIndex).

Comment: Well, then if you get empty back, it's because it's the value that's selected. Hence the 'what data do you have' question.

Comment: Don't see how it's possible to return anything other than the GUID. I just gave up and modified the SP to change it to a String when it's picked up, changed my data object to see it as a string and ta da! there it is in the app. Not EMPTY but the string representation of the GUID. Still don't know why the reader could not read it as a GUID, but I was going to convert it later to a string anyway. So I'm done, can't waste any more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out the data-type of any "I got an issue" column..is something like this.

```
c#

object obj = dataReader.GetValue(123);
```

My vb.net attempt of a translation

```
dim obj as object = dataReader.GetValue(123)
```

"123" is the ORDINAL of the Select Statement.

Now, when the code run, let the line (above) run.
Stop it on a breakpoint after the line above.

Then QuickWatch or put your mouse over it, and you can figure out the datatype and its value.

.........

You should also be putting null checks around the "setting".

c# code

```
if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(123)))
    {
        string x = dataReader.GetString(123);
    }
```

You'll have to do the vb.net translation.

Comment: Thanks, GranadaCoder. I will see if that tells me anything. I really don't need a Null check here as this is a auto generated GUID in the database and the record cannot exist with out it. As you can see in the code, I did do a Null check on the index. I will let you know if the datatype check helps...

Comment: Yep,same result (GUID type, Value EMPTY). Of course the Public Sub would not even be called if it was anything other than a GUID type.

Comment: There is a whole set of overloaded setObjectProperty subs, so the proper one is auto selected due to the type of the data.

Comment: Gave up and just converted it to a string in the stored proceedure. Change my local data type from a GUID to a string and now it comes over just fine. Who know's why I couldn't retrive it as a GUID, but I'm moving on. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: If you get it with "GetValue", and the debugger shows its type as "System.Guid", then I don't get it.  GetGuid() should work.